# i m doing the project on NFC , can i implement it on the non nfc mobile phones

Tags: android, ios, nfc, android-networking

hello guys I am doing the Project on the NFC tags I have the doubt can I connect  NFC to the NON-NFC Mobile phones , if any one friends got any ideas please be free to share with me as soon as possible

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not logical, you cannot do something on hardware you clearly state is not capable of doing that action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. NFC is hardware feature. Despite Android system has platform tools for interacting with NFC module installed on device, you can't use those tools if hardware module is absent.

Comment: then how can i connect to the non nfc based mobile phones to the nfc tags , if any ideas please share as soon as possible ., my humble request

Comment: You just can't.

Comment: if any ideas can u share with me , i m really  interested in this ,  if any how can we able to connect please let me know